# The meaning of the Middle English word “king”

Tags: orthography, middle-english, handwriting

Why was the word (?verb?) "king" used in [this (page 63)](https://www.originalbibles.com/wycliffe-bible-new-testament-1400-pdf/) [Mk.2:6](https://old.bibleonline.ru/bible/eng/41/02/#6) part of the Wycliffe Bible?
The King James Version
Mk.2:6
But there were certain of the scribes sitting there, and **reasoning** in their hearts

[image]

Furthermore the ordinary Middle English spelling of this word ('as a noun') in this source is "kyng".

[image]

Answer (score 27):

It's the second half of the word "thinking", (or "thenking") with the first half being at the end of the previous line.

A [modern rendition of the Wycliffe translation](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=mark%202%3A6&version=WYC) has

> But there were some of the scribes sitting, and thinking in their hearts

(or "but the were sume of the scribis sittyng y thenking in her hertis")

You can clearly see the words for 'scribis' and 'sittyng' and 'hertis', and you can also see another place where a word is split, "sume", between the end of the line two above the red circle and the beginning of the line above it.

Splitting a word was not unusual in those days. Writing materials were rare enough not to waste space where a word could be started in it, and finished on the next line.

Comment: Nor is it unusual today, although (as you know) in modern English we would always insert a hyphen.

Comment: it's pretty unusual if you consider how much digital writing people consume these days. it seems like word-breaking is off by default on most platforms and applications. (*i* put the hyphen in `word-breaking` there and SE styling seems to take that as a potential line break boundary, but other long words near the edge of the container don't get the same treatment and don't get automatic hyphen insertion)